# How do I add a row to my list view?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I can't seem to get this to work. Anyone have any ideas why?

Here is the markup:

```
<ListView Width="210" Height="83" Margin="0 0 5 0" Name="FiltersListView">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Column" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FilterColumn}"></GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Rule" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FilterRule}"></GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="String" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FilterString}"></GridViewColumn>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
```

Here is the window initializer:

```
public SelectionWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rows = new List<Row>();
        // Create a new binding object and set the binding of this list view to it.
        Binding myBinding = new Binding();
        myBinding.Source = rows;
        FiltersListView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
    }
```

Here is my rows object and class:

```
List<Row> rows;
public class Row
    {
        public string FilterColumn;
        public string FilterRule;
        public string FilterString;
    }
```

But when I click this button, I don't see it getting added to the list:

```
private void AddButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding row.");
            rows.Add(new Row { FilterColumn = "1", FilterRule = "2", FilterString = "3" });
            Console.WriteLine("Row added.");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `List<int>` doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so the control doesn't know that the list has actually been updated.

Try to make `rows` an `ObservableColelction<Row>`.

---

Edit: as the OP mentioned, the other problem (empty rows) was due to using fields, not properties, on `Row`.

Comment: It works partially now. I see that rows get added, but rows seem to all be blank. Any ideas why?

Comment: Also is there a way to set all of this up in the ASMX?

Comment: @Alexandru: not sure if `Width="Auto"` is true -- could you please try with a constant width?

Comment: @Alexandru: I've got no experience with ASP, so sorry, no clue about asmx.

Comment: It looks like the trick was to add getters and setters on the Row's properties. Now I can see the rows! :D
public class Row
{
    public string FilterColumn { get; set; }
    public string FilterRule { get; set; }
    public string FilterString { get; set; }
}